# NotNumber in XPath

Tags: parsing, xpath

The w3c working draft "Building a Tokenizer for XPath or XQuery" mentions a `NotNumber`. I can't find any references for this. What is this?

Reference: https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-xpath-parsing/#DEFAULT_xpath

There: "2.1.2 XPath Lexical States"

The first table matches the pattern "NotNumber" amongst others. Is this like the IEEE 754 NaN?

The same question is about `NotOperatorKeyword`, which also does not have a reference.